# Why am I getting ranked high for numerical queries?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines

On one day, someone made a search on google for the query "59". According to GSC search analytics, this query made it to position 2 which is odd. However, when I search in google itself for "59", my site doesn't show up as #2 nor does it show up on the first page. I don't care if my site doesn't rank high solely on numbers.

My question is why does google do this? Is their search analytics for GSC a bit broken?

Comment: It's an error and one that can occur often in both analytics and wmt.

Comment: Its pretty bad for the search engine giant to be producing errors without at least some sort of disclaimer about it on the same page.

Comment: Traditionally, search engines do not hit upon numeric searches without another non-numeric search term. Google at one point said that they do not do numeric searches, however, did a search for *pi*, cut and pasted the result into another search and it clearly does at least search for *3.14159265359* (pi). Numeric searches are likely not important most of the time unless it is specific. 59 is not specific so I would disregard what G is saying as utter useless gibberish and not worry about it. Cheers!!